# How to add files sub icon with Visual Studio Package?

Tags: visual-studio, package, vspackage

I'm writing a Visual Studio extension where I want user to select few specific file in solution explorer. I already moved my command to solution explorer part using .vsct file. Now I would like to mark user selected files with sub icons like AnkhSVN (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/E721D830-7664-4E02-8D03-933C3F1477F2?SRC=Home) does (see image).

[image: AnkhSVN sub icons]

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

That's called overlay icon and it's a property of IVsHierarchy:

IVsHierarchy.SetProperty method:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivshierarchy.setproperty.aspx

VSHPROPID_OverlayIconIndex property:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.__vshpropid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

And "index" refers to the image list with the icons (that your package doesn't own). So unfortunately I think that with that approach you can use only use the given icons, so you may want to explore the approach that Source Control providers (such as AnkhSVN) must use:

Glyph Control (Source Control VSPackage)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166345.aspx

Comment: Hi Carlos,
How should I use VSHPROPID_OverlayIconIndex if standart Visual Studio images is enough for me?